# Best Ubuntu Server version for Windows ME computer

Tags: wireless, server

I have a very very old HP Pavilion 6835 that formally ran Windows ME. I'm currently looking at installing Ubuntu Server on it to host some files, but it is only capable of running anything that is able to run under 128mb of RAM for long periods of time. (I have tried Puppy Linux which works fine, but when left alone for more than 5 min it no longer responds.) Ubuntu appears to be more stable, but its current versions fall short of the requirements I need.

I do not know if this is also important to mention, but wired connections are out of the question. I *must* have wireless capabilities or else I just wasted a CD.

Comment: You better go and grab some used RAM module to upgrade your box. It will help you to find more easily some OS suitable to run on it.  Ubuntu Server (CLI) requires at minimum 192MB.

Comment: Ubuntu Snappy Core may work - it says [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/01/21/snappy-ubuntu-core-is-an-iot-linux-distribution-for-arm-and-x86/) that it can use 128Mb... I am also not sure if supports using a display as well. Also, [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/50184/178596) says Lubuntu 14.04 should work.

Comment: You'd better have at least 256MB RAM for Ubuntu Server **minimal** installation. Buying antique DIMM 168-pin RAM for a machine that old is likely to cost a lot more than simply buying a Raspberry Pi 2 and installing Ubuntu Server on it. The Raspberry Pi 2 will also be more energy efficient than your HP Pavilion 6835.

Comment: I cannot buy upgrades or buy more computers. I do not have the money no matter how cheap it may be.

Comment: @Wilf I cannot find a direct image to download. I do not think it may be compatible with my machine either.